# Installing Tizen SDK on another partition in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sdk

I'm a newbie with Ubuntu & I'm trying to install tizen SDK but my boot partition is full, as I'm using Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, but I do have another partition that have enough space to run the tizen sdk, but I don’t know how to install it, is it possible to install it?

Comment: Have you consider a [virtual machine](https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/IVI/IVI_3.0_VMware)?

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from the webpage https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/tizen-sdk but you have to download sdk manager and sdk image for your system. Then after dawnloading, open the terminal and write commands as below. First go to your folder where you downloaded it, for example if u downloaded it in the downoads folder type in terminal: 'cd Downloads' and then type 'chmod +x tizen-sdk-Your version-ubuntu.bin' but now the version i used to download is 'tizen-sdk-ubuntu32-v2.2.71.bin'. After u did that type again './tizen-sdk--ubuntu.bin', for mine it was './tizen-sdk--ubuntu.bin'. Then its a window that u will see. click advanced and put your sdk image over there and then keep going until its finished....Hope it works

Comment: sorry, Type ./tizen-sdk-Your version-ubuntu.bin , but even if u dont know u can check it whats their name in the folder where u downloaded them...